# Conversion of tilestache cache into mbtiles

Tags: tilestache, mapbox

I have read and I am looking for someone with documentation on how to achieve converting a cache generated by tilecache into mbtiles using mainly mbtiles. I see the mbtiles has an import function but it requires a metadata.json which tilecache does not have and also it seems the --scheme option has been depricated.

I am trying to use mb-util -i tiles world.mbtiles and hopefully I would like to open the mbtiles in qgis

Answer (score 1):

You can use tilestache to output to a mbtiles, it is documented here [Documentation](http://tilestache.org/doc/TileStache.MBTiles.html)

Looking at this you change the configuration file to have

```
"provider":
{
"name": "mbtiles",
"tileset": "collection.mbtiles"
}
```